# Is there any online website that allows you to test form submissions

Tags: html, forms

Hello I would like this for a client. Are there any online websites that simply show the variables sent to them after a GET form submission ? Google did not help.

Comment: https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/

Comment: I like http://requestb.in/

Comment: Are you trying to see what user defined variables are submitted by the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one here:

http://myhttp.info/?xxx=123

```
Request method  GET
Request URI /?xxx=123
Request protocol    HTTP/1.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept charset  
Accept encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept language en-CA,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Connection  keep-alive
Host    myhttp.info
Referer https://www.google.ca/
User agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/), after creating your RequestBin you get an URL like this one http://requestb.in/orrtsoor. Change the destination of your form to that URL. After making some requests you can inspect them there http://requestb.in/orrtsoor?inspect.
The FORM/POST PARAMETERS as well as the HEADERS for each request are displayed.

**Example:** GET http://requestb.in/orrtsoor?oneparameter=test

QUERYSTRING

```
oneparameter: test
```

HEADERS

```
X-Request-Id: 38c3bc1c-4d2e-403d-bb85-ec385e545851
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
Host: requestb.in
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: close
Cookie: session=eyJyZWNlbnQisib3JydHNvb3IiXX0.BbsQyA.bRv2HD0wxXBt
```